# Jeuclid drops parts while running as servlet

Tags: java, servlets, math, svg, mathml

I try to use jeuclid as servlet. For that reason I use the net.sourceforge.jeuclid.converter.Converter

```
         MutableLayoutContext ctx = new LayoutContextImpl(
               LayoutContextImpl.getDefaultLayoutContext());

         Converter converter = Converter.getInstance();

         converter.convert(new File(argsList.get("input")[0]),
                       new File(argsList.get("output")[0]), Converter.TYPE_SVG, ctx);
```

…

But in these 3 files you can see that some parts are dropped.

Source: http://www.samea.de/math/source.mml

Expected: http://www.samea.de/math/expected.svg (done with the mml2xxx batch)

Result: http://www.samea.de/math/result.svg (done with the code above)

So what did I wrong? Are there some parameters to set?
Thanks for your help

Kind regards

Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at least I found out it was the version of jetty.
So I switched from Jetty9 to Jetty8.

bye
Markus